Assertion Error in Custom ListTile Using Flutter FormBuilder's CheckboxListTile in Debug Mode
I have forked the Flutter ListTile and created my own custom list tile widget. Inside this custom list tile, I am using a checkbox from the flutter_form_builder package, which internally uses CheckboxListTile. The issue I am facing is an assertion error in debug mode, but it does not occur in release mode. Here is the error message:
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
Leading widget consumes entire tile width. Please use a sized widget, or consider replacing ListTile with a custom widget (see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html#material.ListTile.4)
'package:flutter/src/material/list_tile.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1318 pos 7: 'tileWidth != leadingSize.width || tileWidth == 0.0'

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.yml

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  CheckboxListTile CheckboxListTile:file:///Users/umair.k/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_form_builder-9.2.1/lib/src/fields/form_builder_checkbox.dart:128:22
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      _RenderListTile.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/list_tile.dart:1318:7)
#3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#4      RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#5      RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:239:12)
#6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#7      RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#8      RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:239:12)
#9      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#10     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#11     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#13     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#14     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#15     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#16     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#17     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#19     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#20     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#21     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#22     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#23     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#25     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#26     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#27     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#28     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#29     _RenderDecoration._layoutLineBox (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:923:9)
#30     _RenderDecoration._layout (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:1045:28)
#31     _RenderDecoration.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:1364:44)
#32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#33     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#34     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:280:14)
#35     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#36     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#37     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:52:11)
#38     RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:809:43)
#39     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:904:32)
#40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#41     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#42     _RenderListTile._layoutBox (package:widgetbook_tlf/src/widgets/coruscant_list_item/list_item/custom_list_tile.dart:1340:9)
#43     _RenderListTile.performLayout (package:widgetbook_tlf/src/widgets/coruscant_list_item/list_item/custom_list_tile.dart:1386:31)
#44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#45     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#46     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:239:12)
#47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#48     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#49     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:239:12)
#50     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#51     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#52     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#54     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#55     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#56     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#57     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#58     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#59     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#60     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#61     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#62     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#63     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#64     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#65     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#66     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#67     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#68     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#69     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#70     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#71     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1440:11)
#72     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#73     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#74     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#75     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#76     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#77     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#78     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#79     RenderBox.layout (package

I have commented out the relevant assertion in my custom list tile to prevent the error, but the assertion still fails when flutter_form_builder's CheckboxListTile is called internally.
This issue only occurs in debug mode and not in release mode. How can I resolve this assertion error while using my custom list tile with the flutter_form_builder package in debug mode?
Code for the CheckboxListTile:
      /// Creates a single Checkbox field
  FormBuilderCheckbox({
    super.key,
    required super.name,
    super.validator,
    super.initialValue,
    super.decoration = const InputDecoration(
      border: InputBorder.none,
      focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
      errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
      disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
    ),
    super.onChanged,
    super.valueTransformer,
    super.enabled,
    super.onSaved,
    super.autovalidateMode = AutovalidateMode.disabled,
    super.onReset,
    super.focusNode,
    super.restorationId,
    required this.title,
    this.activeColor,
    this.autofocus = false,
    this.checkColor,
    this.contentPadding = EdgeInsets.zero,
    this.visualDensity,
    this.controlAffinity = ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
    this.secondary,
    this.selected = false,
    this.subtitle,
    this.tristate = false,
    this.shape,
    this.side,
  }) : super(
          builder: (FormFieldState<bool?> field) {
            final state = field as _FormBuilderCheckboxState;

            return InputDecorator(
              decoration: state.decoration,


                      child: CheckboxListTile(
                        dense: true,
                        isThreeLine: false,
                        title: title,
                        subtitle: subtitle,
                        value: tristate ? state.value : (state.value ?? false),
                        onChanged: state.enabled
                            ? (value) {
                          state.didChange(value);
                        }
                            : null,
                        checkColor: checkColor,
                        activeColor: activeColor,
                        secondary: secondary,
                        controlAffinity: controlAffinity,
                        autofocus: autofocus,
                        tristate: tristate,
                        contentPadding: contentPadding,
                        visualDensity: visualDensity,
                        selected: selected,
                        checkboxShape: shape,
                        side: side,
                      )


              
            );
          },
        );

  @override
  FormBuilderFieldDecorationState<FormBuilderCheckbox, bool> createState() =>
      _FormBuilderCheckboxState();
}

class _FormBuilderCheckboxState
    extends FormBuilderFieldDecorationState<FormBuilderCheckbox, bool> {}

The way I am adding checkbox:
      Widget _getCheckbox() {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 35,
      child: CoruscantCheckboxWidget(
        isBackgroundDark: false,
        isChecked: _isCheckboxSelected,
        onChanged: _onTap,
      ),
    );
  }

I am just adding the above checkbox in my custom tile list item trailing widget this check box in debug mode calls the assertion.
Here how the checkbox is being used in trailing and leading:
   Widget? _getLeading() {
    if (widget.leadingIcon != null) {
      return _getCircleAvatar(
        icon: widget.leadingIcon!.icon,
        circleColor: widget.leadingIcon!.circleColor,
        iconColor: widget.leadingIcon!.iconColor,
        gradient: widget.leadingIcon!.gradient,
      );
    }
    if (widget.status != null) {
      return SizedBox(
        width: 65,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _getCircleAvatar(
              icon: widget.status!.icon,
              circleColor: widget.status!.circleColor,
              iconColor: widget.status!.color,
              gradient: widget.status!.gradient,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    widget.status!.label,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: CoruscantTextStyles.bodySmall.copyWith(
                      color: widget.status!.color,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    if (widget.leadingNetworkImage != null) {
      return Container(
        height: 52,
        width: 52,
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(6),
          ),
        ),
        child: Image.network(
          widget.leadingNetworkImage!,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      );
    }
    if (widget.showCheckbox) {
      return _getCheckbox();
    }
    return null;
  }

  // Returns the trailing widget depending on the type of the ListItem. It can
  // return a checkbox, an amount text, chevron and checked icons or nothing.
  Widget? _getTrailing() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        if (widget.showCheckbox && widget.leadingIcon != null)
          _getCheckbox()
        else if (widget.amount != null)
          Text(
            widget.amount!,
            style: CoruscantTextStyles.titleLarge.withColor(
              (_isItemSelected && widget.isSelectable)
                  ? _ListItemColors.amountSelected
                  : _ListItemColors.amount,
            ),
          ),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        _getTrailingWidget(),
      ],
    );
  }


Hi, could you add a snippet of your code ?

what part of code should I post since the list tile is completely forked from flutter @HCKRMVT I just changed the height

A widget provided in secondary property needs to have constant size like Icon or Text.
CheckboxListTile(
  title: const Text('Title'),
  secondary: const Icon(Icons.settings),
...
)


so I am using my custom list tile which has a check box from form builder package that check box is wrapped in sized box already and that checkbox is the one calling  CheckboxListTile

Wrapping CheckboxListTile or its parents doesn't help. secondary widget is the issue.

I am not even passing the secondary widget

Without sharing the code, I doubt anybody can help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

I have shared the checkboxListTileCode
